# Using trapz to integrate a column vector

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I'm trying to use the function trapz to integrate a column vector of EMG data.

> trapz(G);

However, it keeps coming up with the warning:

'Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals'

I'm a complete novice so I am unsure why this is happening. All the values in my column vector are positive, and all of the online examples I have seen seem to be similar to mine yet mine does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: When you type in `which trapz`, does it show the path to the trapz.m or `trapz is a variable`?

Comment: It says trapz is a variable

Comment: You have a variable `trapz` in your workspace which is shadowing the function `trapz` - MATLAB assumes you want the variable rather than the function.  Do `clear trapz` to remove the variable.

Comment: That has fixed the problem. It is always something simple. Thank you everyone who has responded to my question